# FBX file import into Unity with armature gives Shader error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I was importing objects as Fbx files into Unity scene with following code;

```
        GameObject preFab = AssetDatabase.
                               LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>("Assets/name.fbx");
       
        GameObject newTarget = Instantiate(preFab);

        Renderer renderer = newTarget.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

But when I add armatures in the objects I start to get

```
 **MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "name" game object, but a script is trying to access it.**
```

error.

Could not find a solution.

Comment: Is there anything you don't understand about this error message?

Comment: Yes there is, armature does not need shader but Unity wants it.

Comment: Shader or renderer? If the armature doesn't need a renderer, why do you get it?

Comment: Renderer as in error message. Do you understand why it is requested for armature.

Comment: You request it here: `newTarget.GetComponent<Renderer>();`

Comment: It looks that it is not about Armatures actually, when I adding Armatures I added several other objects as well so they should be imported separately in a loop  I think. I dont erase question when I solve it I answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

You created an object in Blender and this object consists of collection of several separate meshes let's say a cube and a cylinder.

Because you want to animate them with Unity script instead of make animation in Blender which is my case.

You selected them and exported them as FBX file without changing any
export parameter.

Then you dragged them Unity's asset console.

Now you will include them into your scene one script class.
The name of FBX file is "trt" in that case.
The following code loads every asset! in this file.

```
 Object[] assets = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("Assets/trt.fbx");
```

Now you loop all read things with

```
  GameObject newTarget = new GameObject("FBXContainer");
  foreach (Object asset in assets)
            {
                if (asset is GameObject)
                {
```

first if in loop checks if "asset" was GameObject or not but unfortunately
name of fbx file with multiple meshes pass this check as if it was GameObject so in following steps if you try the read renderer of it causing renderer error when you run game.

So I added second if to skip "trt". If your object is one mesh object fbx name considered as mesh name so you dont have to skip.

```
                    if (!asset.name.Contains ("trt")
                    {

                      
                      Renderer renderer = instantiatedObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                      GameObject newTargetChild = Instantiate(instantiatedObject);
     
     ...........

                     }

                 }
              }
```

If you export armatures and bones that causing the same type of problem so I decided to make animation with #C script.